# Dialpad and Dual Channel Recordings

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

The documentation found here, [Known Limitations](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/admin-guide/setup/voice/dialpad-limitations) has a section stating:

> Dual channel recording requires recordingStatusCallback to be set
> The recordingStatusCallback attribute must be set in the Conference instruction attributes when enabling dual channel recording. See this [support article](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360010785673-Call-Recording-with-Twilio-Flex?_ga=2.123731336.2030817929.1657480895-1950107106.1657299582) for more information.

But the referenced support article does not provide any information on Dual Channel recordings.

There is a code snippet:

```
flex.Actions.addListener("beforeAcceptTask", (payload) => {
  payload.conferenceOptions.record = 'true';
  payload.conferenceOptions.recordingStatusCallback = 'https://example.com/recordingcallbackurl';
});
```

Which I believe generates a mono recording, not a dual channel (stereo) recording. Any suggestions where to look or can you provide some clarity around this? Not clear about the requirement for:

> The recordingStatusCallback attribute must be set in the Conference instruction attributes

Answer (score 0):

To generate a dual channel recording, I think you need to add the [`recordingChannels` option, set to "dual"](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/recording#optional-parameters):

```js
flex.Actions.addListener("beforeAcceptTask", (payload) => {
  payload.conferenceOptions.record = 'true';
  payload.conferenceOptions.recordingStatusCallback = 'https://example.com/recordingcallbackurl';
  payload.conferenceOptions.recordingChannels = 'dual'
});
```